# (DONE) How is this question "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[How to find workplaces with high proportion of young (20-something) college-educated population?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125280/how-to-find-workplaces-with-high-proportion-of-young-20-something-college-educ)

I don't understand how this could possibly be considered too broad. Can anyone help?

I voted to reopen. Perhaps you would like to do the same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question has been re-opened

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, though it's fine to note that it has been reopened as part of an answer (e.g. "It's not too broad, which is why the question has been reopened") or simply as a comment. I'm guessing that's why it's gathered a few downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Where is this person looking - small town, major city, rurality?

How far are they willing to commute or relocate?

What skills, hard and soft, do they currently have?

What qualifications are they expected to obtain?

Why exactly are they interested in the somewhat arbitrary list of industries they put in the question?

What experience in the workplace do they already have?

The question is obviously too broad for Stack Exchange.

Comment: The question is similar to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93579/how-to-find-a-job-with-as-little-social-interaction-with-coworkers-as-possible. That one was quite possible to answer without knowing all the details you propose. Your clarifying questions could have been posed as comments and might have elicited the details you seek. (Although I'm not sure why "Why exactly are they interested in the somewhat arbitrary list of industries" is relevant.)

Comment: Many of those, if specified, would actually make the question “too localised”. I’m not sure they would actually improve the question.

Comment: So the question is either impossible to determine a complete adequate answer for, or an adequate answer would not be helpful to other users in the future. And there are multiple people who something think that's the quality worth having on SE? Mayhap they need to go back to Quora and let the rest of us put something worthwhile back together.